# Uncaught TypeError: tinymce.create is not a function in tinyMCE-mention

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-6

I got this error "Uncaught TypeError: tinymce.create is not a function" in plugin.min.js. I used [tinyMCE-mention](https://github.com/StevenDevooght/tinyMCE-mention)

**Code Snippet:**

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: '#comment.tinymce-editor',
        toolbar_mode: 'floating',
        height: 300,
        toolbar: 'undo redo | fontfamily | emoticons' ,
        toolbar_groups: {
        alignment: {
                icon: 'align-left',
                items: 'alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify'
            }
        },
        branding: false,
        statusbar: false,
        promotion: false,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: 'lists link autolink emoticons mention',
        setup: function(editor) {
            editor.on('change', function() {
                tinymce.triggerSave();
            });
        },

        mentions: {
            source: [
                { name: 'Tyra Porcelli' }, 
                { name: 'Brigid Reddish' },
                { name: 'Ashely Buckler' },
                { name: 'Teddy Whelan' }
            ]
        },
    });
```

**Environment Details:**
Browser: Chrome - Version 113.0.5672.126
TinyMCE version: "^6.4.2"

**Additional Information:**
The issue persists even when trying the same code in the "tinymce-mention" library's runkit environment, which can be accessed using the following URL: https://npm.runkit.com/tinymce-mention